# como funciona el maping en spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.repository.Repository;

import net.javabeat.spring.data.domain.Book;

public interface BookNamedQueryRepositoryExample extends Repository<Book, Long> {
    // Query will be used from Named query defined at Entity class
    List<Book> findByPrice(long price);
}
```

Revisé el proyecto completo, y no hay en ningún lado la implementación del método, pero funciona cuando hago la prueba, que clase de magia es esta? por que funciona si no hay su implementación?

Answer (score 2):

Spring Data JPA utiliza una librería llamada *Javassist (JAVA programming ASSISTant)* para agregar una implementación en tiempo de ejecución a cada interfaz que extiende de `org.springframework.data.repository.Repository`.